# The Database Structure for a Recruiting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit of a noob, and wanted to confirm with you guys if I'm on the right track, in regard to modelling an Job recruiting application.

**There are users**

Each user fills out details, and records 1 video.

**There are jobs.**

Each job has 1 or 2 specific questions about the job. 
Users apply to jobs by filling in the 1 or 2 specific questions.

*Based on this,*

**we'll have the User Model.**

The User model will have the attributes name, email, degree, pref_city etc, video_id

The user has_many jobs

Then, **there's the Job Model.** 
jobs belong_to users

*I'm about a confused as to how this model will play out*

each job will have job_title, job_desc, salary, etc, as well as custom_question1, custom_question2.

When admin creates the job, they will write custom questions for 1 and 2.

Then, when a user applies to the job, they would answer those questions. **However, where would I record the answers to the custom questions?**

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is a many to one relationship between jobs and users. User can apply to many jobs and jobs can have many applications; right? You can use the following structure for a more robust model:

```
User
  has_many :jobs, through: :applications

Job
  has_many :users, through :applications
  has_many :questions

Application
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :answers

Question
  belongs_to :job
  has_one :answer

Answer
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :question
```

I really think instead of linking answers to a user, they should be linked to applications.

Comment: Hi Akash, I'm getting close to finishing the first version, but am stuck on creating the has_many :through relationship with applications. Here's a question I asked on a different thread, would would love your insigh on it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813233/nested-form-complex-has-many-through

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would break the questions and answers away from the `job` itself in order to have more rails magic, because we do love our meta.

So it would look more like this:

```
User
  has_many :jobs
Job
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions
  has_many :applications
Application
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
Question
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :job
Answer
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
```

This way you can always do get a list of current answers for a given job by saying

```
@job.questions.first.answers
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a Job to belong to only one User. Seems like lots of Users will apply for a Job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Below code set should give you some idea. Sounds like an awesome project. Have fun!

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs # jobs this user posted
  has_many :job_applications
  has_many :user_answers

# job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :job_applications

# question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many user_answers
  belongs_to :job  

# job_application.rb
class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job

# user_answer.rb
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  # has a column "answer text..."
```

Comment: hah.. ok, I give up, you're 2 for 2 today - whether you type faster or think faster -- either way I'm beat :)

Comment: What do you think about the answer, though? About beating you, I am on the look-out for helping folks today. That's all. I am about to go to bed. So, have a great night and have fun! :D

Comment: I like Yosep's introduction of a Job application. It did not make sense for a Job to belong to just one user. But a Job Application could belong to one user and one job. If a user applies to more than one job, he would have multiple job application instances. If you wanted to be really clever, you could make Questions polymorphic. So Question `belongs_to :questionable, polymorphic :true` and Job would have `has_many :questions, as: questionable` This would allow additional future classes like WorkExperience, Skills, etc. to also have many questions.

Answer (score 1):

http://bit.ly/1giMQIl

It would help to know more about your project. I went the safe route and assumed a couple things:

- The questions on applications can change
- You want to remember user answers if those questions changed